# Cross compile from linux to ARM-ELF (ARM926EJ-S/MT7108)

Tags: linux, gcc, arm

I have installed all cross compile packages on my ubuntu system so far but am having a
problem and need some help.

```
Processor       : ARM926EJ-S rev 5 (v5l)
BogoMIPS        : 184.72
Features        : swp half thumb fastmult edsp java
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 5TEJ
CPU variant     : 0x0
CPU part        : 0x926
CPU revision    : 5
Cache type      : write-back
Cache clean     : cp15 c7 ops
Cache lockdown  : format C
Cache format    : Harvard
I size          : 32768
I assoc         : 4
I line length   : 32
I sets          : 256
D size          : 32768
D assoc         : 4
D line length   : 32
D sets          : 256

Hardware        : MT7108
Revision        : 0000
Serial          : 0000000000000000
```

This is the target machine I need to cross compile for. What flags should I
use when compiling?

Comment: Do you HAVE a cross-compiler installed?

Comment: The *Linux version*, `grep ABI .config` and `ls -l /lib/libc*` on the target would be helpful, if you can provide any of them.

Comment: yes I have cross-compilers installed.. I have: gcc-arm-none-eabi, gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi, gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf, gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu, and what dir should I grep ABI .config in?

Comment: lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root           19 Oct 11  2011 /lib/libc.so.0 -> libuClibc-0.9.29.so
-rwxrwxr-x    1 root     root        39088 Oct 11  2011 /lib/libcgi.so
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root        39020 Oct 11  2011 /lib/libcli_api.so
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root        13212 Oct 11  2011 /lib/libcrypt-0.9.29.so
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root           18 Oct 11  2011 /lib/libcrypt.so.0 -> libcrypt-0.9.29.so
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root       915728 Oct 11  2011 /lib/libcrypto.so
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root           12 Oct 11  2011 /lib/libcrypto.so.0.9.8 -> libcrypto.so

Comment: The stock Ubuntu compilers will not work.  You need a compiler named **arm-unknown-linux-uclibcgnueabi** (or similar); this compiler will match the 'C' library, *ucLibc* that you have on your system.  The *crosstool-ng* has an *arm-unknown-linux-uclibcgnueabi* sample and you could use that as a base and set for *uCLibc v0.9.29*, or look for pre-built versions.  The 2nd part to get right is the Linux version and configuration.  This may not matter as much but **could** still be a stumbling block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`apt-cache search arm | grep ^gcc-` gives the following list,

1. gcc-4.7-aarch64-linux-gnu - GNU C compiler
2. gcc-4.7-arm-linux-gnueabi - GNU C compiler
3. gcc-4.7-arm-linux-gnueabi-base - GCC, the GNU Compiler Collection (base package)
4. gcc-4.7-arm-linux-gnueabihf - GNU C compiler
5. gcc-4.7-arm-linux-gnueabihf-base - GCC, the GNU Compiler Collection (base package)
6. gcc-4.7-multilib-arm-linux-gnueabi - GNU C compiler (multilib files)
7. gcc-4.7-multilib-arm-linux-gnueabihf - GNU C compiler (multilib files)
8. gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu - The GNU C compiler for arm64 architecture
9. gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi - The GNU C compiler for armel architecture
10. gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf - The GNU C compiler for armhf architecture

You should install *gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi* which is an alias for *gcc-4.7-arm-linux-gnueabi*. *gcc-4.7-multilib-arm-linux-gnueabi* is also possible, but more complicated.  Use the flags, `-march=armv5te -mtune=arm926ej-s -msoft-float -mfloat-abi=soft`.  You can do more tuning by specifying the `--param NAME=VALUE` option to `gcc` with parameters tuned to your systems *memory sub-system* timing.

You may not be able to use these `gcc` versions as your *Linux* maybe compiled with **OABI** and/or be quite ancient compared to the one the compiler was built for.  In some cases, the *libc* will call a newer *Linux API*, which may not be present.  If the compiler/libc was not configured to be backwards compatible, then it may not work with your system.  You can use [crosstool-ng](http://crosstool-ng.org/) to create a custom compiler that is built to suit your system, but this is much more complex.

Comment: You also need to match the `libc` on the target in some cases.  For instance, if it is Android's *bionic* or *uClibc* the *eglibc* standard Ubuntu compiler will not work.

Answer (score 6):

You have an `ARMv5` with no floating-point processor. It should have been enough with `-march=armv5` and `-mfloat-abi=soft` flags.

However if those flags doesn't work for you, I would suggest writing the smallest c application for testing the toolchain.

```
/* no includes */
int main(void) {   
    return 42;
}
```

and compiling it with most complete/strict flags

```
$arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -Wall --static -O2 -marm -march=armv5 simple.c -o simple
```

after this, push `simple` to target, run it then issue an `echo $?` to verify if you would get `42`. If it works, try to see if you can get `printf` working. If that one also works, you are pretty much set for everything. If `printf` fails, easiest solution would be to find right toolchain for your target.