# Cross Compile for ARM926EJ-Sid

Tags: gcc, arm, cross-compiling

My ultimate goal is to compile rtorrent for my NAS which is a Synology DS107+. To familiarize myself with cross compiling, I wanted to compile a helloworld. This already turned out to be a big hurdle for a novice as I am.

Executing the program results in a Segmentation Fault. I used [gcc-arm-none-eabi](https://launchpad.net/~terry.guo/+archive/gcc-arm-embedded) to compile it on Ubuntu x84_64.

What tools do I need to compile a program for the target? I also consulted ["Cross compile from linux to ARM-ELF (ARM926EJ-S/MT7108)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17336236/cross-compile-from-linux-to-arm-elf-arm926ej-s-mt7108) and needed a [workaround](http://thehackerworkshop.com/?p=443), because gcc complained that _exit is not declared.

Following, there is more detailed information:

**/proc/cpuinfo**

```
Processor   : ARM926EJ-Sid(wb) rev 0 (v5l)
BogoMIPS    : 499.71
Features    : swp half thumb fastmult vfp edsp 
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 5TEJ
CPU variant : 0x0
CPU part    : 0x926
CPU revision    : 0
Cache type  : write-back
Cache clean : cp15 c7 ops
Cache lockdown  : format C
Cache format    : Harvard
I size      : 32768
I assoc     : 1
I line length   : 32
I sets      : 1024
D size      : 32768
D assoc     : 4
D line length   : 32
D sets      : 256

Hardware    : MV-88fxx81
Revision    : 0000
Serial      : 0000000000000000
```

**uname -a**

```
Linux DiskStation 2.6.15 #1637 Sat May 4 05:59:19 CST 2013
armv5tejl GNU/Linux synology_88f5281_107+
```

**dmesg** (snippets from head that seem informative to me)

```
Linux version 2.6.15 (root@build2) (gcc version 3.4.3 (CSL 2005Q1B) (Marvell 2006Q3))
#1637 Sat May 4 05:59:19 CST 2013
CPU: ARM926EJ-Sid(wb) [41069260] revision 0 (ARMv5TEJ)
Machine: MV-88fxx81
...
Synology Hareware Version: DS107v20
Memory policy: ECC disabled, Data cache writeback
...
CPU0: D VIVT write-back cache
CPU0: I cache: 32768 bytes, associativity 1, 32 byte lines, 1024 sets
CPU0: D cache: 32768 bytes, associativity 4, 32 byte lines, 256 sets
```

**readelf -h busybox** (pulled from the device)

```
ELF Header:
Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 01 01 01 61 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
Class:                             ELF32
Data:                              2's complement, little endian
Version:                           1 (current)
OS/ABI:                            ARM
ABI Version:                       0
Type:                              EXEC (Executable file)
Machine:                           ARM
Version:                           0x1
Entry point address:               0x8de0
Start of program headers:          52 (bytes into file)
Start of section headers:          1319468 (bytes into file)
Flags:                             0x602, has entry point, GNU EABI, software FP, VFP
Size of this header:               52 (bytes)
Size of program headers:           32 (bytes)
Number of program headers:         3
Size of section headers:           40 (bytes)
Number of section headers:         20
Section header string table index: 19
```

**EDIT: Command line**

I used the options `-march=armv5te -mtune=arm926ej-s -mno-long-calls -msoft-float -static`. I also experimented with leaving out *march* oder replaced *mtune* by *mcpu*. Without *static*, it says *not found*. Also tried `-mfpu=vfp` and armel binaries of Debian packages. For example *busybox-static* which runs fine on my HTC Desire S (armv7l), also results in segfault.

Using:

- `arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc` → Segmentation fault
- `arm-none-eabi-gcc` → Segmentation fault (or Illegal instruction, but rarely, can't tell when)
- Haven't tried CodeBench, yet.

The code I tried is:

```
# include <stdlib.h>

void _exit (int x) { while (1) {} } // only needed for arm-none-eabi-gcc

int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {
    return 47;
}
```

Comment: use `arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc` toolchain from `codesourcery`

Comment: I downloaded the [toolchain](http://sourcery.mentor.com/public/gnu_toolchain/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/arm-2013.05-24-arm-none-linux-gnueabi-i686-pc-linux-gnu.tar.bz2) but it's only i386, but I have amd64 (Ubuntu target). Is there another option or should I try it in a VM?

Particularly interesting is the value `OS/ABI: ARM` of readelf. The tools I used did not produce that.

Comment: I just succeeded by using packages gcc, libnsl, binutils and libc-dev from [nslu2](http://ipkg.nslu2-linux.org/feeds/optware/syno-x07/cross/unstable/). However, I am still interested in how to cross compile.

Comment: It seems to be a custom minimal linux, so no dpkg. rtorrent is also available from [NSLU2](http://ipkg.nslu2-linux.org/feeds/optware/syno-x07/cross/unstable/). However, this version is dated and I consider this a good exercise to learn about cross compiling.

Comment: Does `cat /etc/issue*` on the *NAS* give a version?